# Ruby multidimensional arrays

Tags: ruby, arrays, search, element

I have a multidimensional array:-

```
arr=  [[ ["paris", "P"], ["spain", "S"] ], [ ["russia", "R"], ["England", "E"] ]...
```

1. I want to pick one element of this array and want to split its elements like ["paris", "P"] and ["spain", "S"]

> ```
> arr.each do |x|
>    arr_new<< el1=x.first and el2=x.last
>    end
> ```

2. given a single element of this arr2 I want to pick the second element and push onto an arr2:-

> ```
> arr2=[]
> arr2<<sec_el1=el1.last and sec_el2=el2.last.
> ```

What is the proper ruby way?

Comment: What's your desired output?

Comment: I want to pick each element of multidimensional array arr [[s,p],[t,x]] break it into [s,p] and [t,x] pass these to a method as arguements. The method then has to pick last element of each of these two elements and downcase them and assign each of them to 2 separate variables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the end result you are looking to achieve is to grab `P`,`S` etc

```
 arr2=[]
 arr=  [["paris", "P"], ["spain", "S"] ], [ ["russia", "R"], ["England", "E"] ]
 arr.flatten.each_with_index{ |e,i| (arr2 << e) if i.odd?}
 puts arr2 #=> ["P", "S", "R", "E"]
```